# EE1 - Every URL Displays Homepage

Tags: url, ee1

I'm updating an EE1 site to v2, but first I need to get it set up on my local server. The homepage and control panel are working great, but every URL on the site displays the homepage template.

Not sure what additional information would be useful here, please let me know and I'll post it, thanks!

- EE 1.6.8
- Structure 1.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to go into the CP in Admin > System Preferences > Output and Debugging and set "Force Query Strings" to yes.

If that still doesn't work, please open up your primary index.php (root of your site) and change qtype to 1.

Do either of those fix it up?

Comment: Changing the qtype to 0 worked (it was at 2 before). Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure! :)